# Unity3d - Coroutine in For Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm working in Unity3D, C# specifically, and I'm trying to write a For loop that instantiates multiple game objects in 1 loop, but I want to stagger their instantiate just slightly, say 0.5 seconds, before the next game object is instantiated.

I figured it would be as simple as doing a normal loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(gameObject, objectSpawn[i].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                StartCoroutine(WeaponsCooldown(6));
            }
            StartCoroutine(WeaponsCooldown(2));
```

and in my couroutine i have a switch case so i can reuse it multiple times (think multiple hard points on a ship or something)

```
IEnumerator WeaponsCooldown(int coolTrigger)
{
    switch (coolTrigger)
    {
    case 1:
        mainFire = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        mainFire = false;
        break;

    case 2:
        leftFire = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        leftFire = false;
        break;
...down to case 6 (for this project)
```

The results that I'm getting are thus:
The StartCoroutine that is outside the for loop fires just fine - this is the master cooldown for that weapon and keeps the player from spam firing it.
However, the startcoroutine inside the for loop does not seem to slow the for loop down any and I'm so new to Unity3D scripting and C# I'm not entirely sure how to troubelshoot this.

I'm assuming that StartCoroutine is a seperate thread that runs aside from the Update thread and that's why the For loop is continuing, because it isn't waiting for the coroutine to finish.

If that is the case, would anyone have any ideas (other than putting individual scripts on each hard point of the player and setting staggering start times (or game object instantiate delays) on each one?

The main reason I wanted to do it all in 1 script is that the player could have upwards of 25 hard points and this would make it a lot easier to reuse on multiple ships with fewer hard points and easier to manage for me personally later on.

Thank you all for any insight offered in advance,
Nick Willcox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the startcoroutine inside the for loop does not seem to slow
>   the for loop

No it doesn't. The result of your script is to instantiate all GameObject in the same frame as well as starting all your coroutines (which one has a different cooldown lasting for a different time).

> I'm assuming that StartCoroutine is a seperate thread that runs aside
>   from the Update thread and that's why the For loop is continuing,
>   because it isn't waiting for the coroutine to finish.

No :). Coroutines lives all in the same thread. They are just [iterator blocks](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx). [Citing](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) Jon Skeet:

> In C# 2, the compiler does all the hard work for you when you use
>   iterator blocks to implement either IEnumerable or IEnumerator (or the
>   generic forms). It builds a state machine for you, and the iterator
>   obtained effectively executes the code within the iterator block,
>   yielding values as it goes.

I think another way to describe them is cooperative multitasking.

> I'm trying to write a For loop that instantiates multiple game objects
>   in 1 loop, but I want to stagger their instantiate just slightly, say
>   0.5 seconds, before the next game object is instantiated.

Without considering the specific behavior you are implementing, a simple way to delay the instantiate calls (0.5 secs) is wrapping the for loop in a coroutine it self:

```
public IEnumerator DelayInstantiate()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
  {
     Instantiate(gameObject, objectSpawn[i].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
     StartCoroutine(WeaponsCooldown(6)); //or do what you want

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel really stupid for not trying that already...I'll give that a go today and reply back the findings, however I wanted to take a quick second to thank you for the time you put into the reply and breaking down various sections of my inquiry.  Thank you greatly and I'll get this tested as soon as possible.

Comment: Marking as complete/best answer.  It totally works!!! Woo!  thank you so much!  I've been fighting this for days now. ><.  lol

Thank you greatly Heisenbug.